# What does the given statement from the documentation of np.empty.mean?

Tags: python, numpy, data-science

In the documentation of `np.empty`, it is given that:

> Object arrays will be initialized to None.

What does it mean?

Comment: `numpy.empty(2, dtype=object)` returns `array([None, None], dtype=object)`. That is basically what it says.

Comment: What did it do when you tested it out?  What do you not understand about that?  What is confusing about example usage you found in your research?

Comment: From [the docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html#numpy.empty):

> Array of uninitialized (arbitrary) data of the given shape, `dtype`, and order. Object arrays will be initialized to `None`.

It means that whenever you define a `numpy` empty, the gaps of the skeleton will be filled with **not `0`s**, **not blanks**, **but *`None`s***. Now applaud.

Answer (score 0):

An object `dtype` array contains references to python objects, which may be numbers, strings, lists, other arrays etc.  To be safe, `empty` fills the array with references to the unique python object `None`. Not only is it safe, it can also be useful.